# vnstat - combine WiFi and Ethernet usage together

Tags: networking, bash, conky, bandwidth, vnstat

My laptop has two network interfaces `enp59s0` and `wlp60s0`. Historically I've always used the Ethernet card (enp59s0) so using `vnstat` to get network consumption for today, yesterday, current week and current month has never been an issue with me.

Recently I've moved and now I'll be using WiFi (wlp60s0). I had to modify my `conky` code:

```
${color}${goto 5}Today ${goto 100}Yesterday ${goto 225}Week ${goto 325}Month ${color green}
# vnstatd updates database every five minutes
${execi 300 vnstat -i wlp60s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print $8" "substr ($9, 1, 1)}'} ${goto 110}${execi 300 vnstat -i wlp60s0 | grep "yesterday" | awk '{print $8" "substr ($9, 1, 1)}'} ${goto 220}${execi 300 vnstat -i wlp60s0 -w | grep "current week" | awk '{print $9" "substr ($10, 1, 1)}'} ${goto 315}${execi 300 vnstat -i wlp60s0 -m | grep "`date +"%b '%y"`" | awk '{print $9" "substr ($10, 1, 1)}'}
```

It is awkward for me to change conky calls to `vntstat` so I would like both `wlp60s0` and `enp59s0` combined together with a bash script. I prefer bash as it is easier for me to maintain. The script is called every 5 minutes so performance impact is nominal.

Not only does would a script save me from changing Conky code dependent on interface, but ISP monthly quota will be accurately tracked with both interfaces added together.

***I prefer a bash script to solve this problem*** but other readers might be interested in C, Java or Python solutions.

Comment: **+1** to both Q and A!

Answer (score 4):

This bash script will add up `vnstat` totals for multiple interfaces:

```
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: vnall
# DESC: Add up multiple interfaces of vnstat into totals for today,
#       yesterday, current week and current month.
# PARM: "today", "yesterday", "week" (current), "month" (current)
# DATE: September 2, 2019. Modified September 4, 2019.

# To discover interfaces `lshw -c network` then place names below
# aInterfaces=( "enp59s0" "wlp60s0" )
# Use automatic discovery if you are unsure of names or don't want to look up
Interfaces=( $(lshw -c network 2>/dev/null | grep name: | cut -d':' -f2) )

Tally () {
    Ktot=0     # Totals in KiB, MiB and GiB
    Mtot=0
    Gtot=0
    # Tally all interfaces
    local i Interface Line Raw ThisNum
    for (( i=0; i<${#aInterfaces[@]}; i++ )) ; do

        Interface="${aInterfaces[i]}"
        if [[ "$vnstatParm" == "" ]] ; then
            Line=$(vnstat -i "$Interface" | grep "$GrepString")
        else
            Line=$(vnstat -i "$Interface" "$vnstatParm" | grep "$GrepString")
        fi

        [[ $Line == "" ]] && continue   # No data collected yet
        if [[ $vnstatParm == "" ]] ; then
            Raw=$(echo "$Line" | awk '{print $8 substr ($9, 1, 1)}')
        else
            Raw=$(echo "$Line" | awk '{print $9 substr ($10, 1, 1)}')
        fi

        ThisNum="${Raw::-1}"    # Number without suffix
        case ${Raw: -1} in      # Decide on last character K, M or G
            K)
                Ktot=$(echo "$Ktot + $ThisNum " | bc) ;;
            M)
                Mtot=$(echo "$Mtot + $ThisNum " | bc) ;;
            G)
                Gtot=$(echo "$Gtot + $ThisNum " | bc) ;;
            *)
                echo "Unknown Unit: ${Raw: -1}" ;;
        esac
    done

    [[ $Gtot != "0" ]] && { echo "$Gtot G" ; return ; }
    [[ $Mtot != "0" ]] && { echo "$Mtot M" ; return ; }
    [[ $Ktot != "0" ]] && { echo "$Ktot K" ; return ; }
    echo "N/A"
} # Tally

Init () {
    GrepString="$1"     # Create defaults for "today" and "yesterday"
    vnstatParm=""
    if [[ $1 == week ]] ; then
        GrepString="current $GrepString"
        vnstatParm="-w"
    fi
    if [[ $1 == month ]] ; then
        GrepString=$(date +"%b '%y")
        vnstatParm="-m"
    fi
} # Init

Init "$@"
Tally
```

### Automatic vs Manual interface names

Notes this section of code:

```
# To discover interfaces `lshw -c network` then place names below
# aInterfaces=( "enp59s0" "wlp60s0" )
# Use automatic discovery if you are unsure of names or don't want to look up
Interfaces=( $(lshw -c network 2>/dev/null | grep name: | cut -d':' -f2) )
```

The fourth line automatically discovers the interface names (in my case `enp59s0` and `wlp60s0`) and builds the array of interfaces (`aInterfaces`). If you prefer to manually specify the names in your script then place a comment (`#`) at the beginning of the line and uncomment the second line by removing the `#` line prefix.

### Conky code shrinks considerably

Because the new `vnall` script automatically creates parameters as needed, the conky code is a lot smaller than before:

```
${color}${goto 5}Today ${goto 100}Yesterday ${goto 225}Week ${goto 325}Month ${color green}
# vnstatd updates database every five minutes
${execi 300 vnall "today"} ${goto 110}${execi 300 vnall "yesterday"} ${goto 220}${execi 300 vnall "week"} ${goto 315}${execi 300 vnall "month"}
```

### Conky Image

[image: vnall.png]

Comment: How to configure vnstat.conf to use two interface ? eth1 and eth2

Comment: @AnasFanani The easiest solution is to try the answer below posted by Teemu.

Answer (score 1):

The `vnstat` command supports merging interface data internally using the `+` syntax as explained by the man page:

```
-i, --iface interface
       Select one specific interface and apply actions to only it. For queries, it is possible to merge the information of two or
       more interfaces using the interface1+interface2+...  syntax.
```

In your case, it's enough to replace `-i wlp60s0` with `-i wlp60s0+enp59s0`.

Comment: Had I not customized `vnall` as a wrapper to `vnstat` this would have been the accepted answer. I had tried `-i wlp60s0 enp59s0` and `-i wlp60s0 enp59s0` without success . I also tried the `vnstat --help` option and google search without success. I wish I had thought of checking manpage though! I should point out your solution is likely more accurate if it adds 512 MiB from one interface to 1 GiB to another to reach 1.5 GiB. My code isn't as granular and currently reports only 1.0 G.

Comment: As the `vnstat` command does the data merging internally, there's no loss of resolution and it's not limited to the summary output. The `--help` output also points out the existence of the man page on the last line. Due to the number of different option combination vnStat has, it hasn't for a long time been practical to list all options in the `--help` output. Even `--longhelp` needs to try to keep some balance between output length and readability.

Comment: Yes I read the last line of `--help` reference to manpage this morning and believe me I'm kicking myself for not seeing it sooner :(